# Looping and copying with condition, column next not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop copy from one sheet to another sheet, with the condition that the cell it copies to is dependent on the right column next to it not being empty. If empty then the loop should stop.

Updated the code to the following:

```vb
Public Sub emptycell()

Dim Conditionalcol As Integer     'this is dependant on the 'column' of names
Conditionalcol = 4
 
Dim Projectrow As Integer         'row empty for project name
Projectrow = 4

Dim Projectdowncell As String     'move down cell for project name pasting
Projectdowncell = 1

Dim projectcellright As Integer   'move  cell right 1 down for project name copying
projectcellright = 5

Do While Sheets("Datacopied").Cells(Conditionalcol, 3) <> "" 'this is the condition to stop at empty cell
    a = Cells(Conditionalcol, 1)
    'copy and paste as per below'
    Sheets("Dataneeded").Cells(projectcellright, 2) _
    .Copy Destination:=Sheets("datacopied").Range("B3") _
    .Offset(Projectdowncell, 0)

    Projectdowncell = Projectdowncell + 1
    projectcellright = projectcellright + 1
    Conditionalcol = Conditionalcol + 1
 
Loop
End Sub
```

When the condition is met, it correctly stops. However I want it to copy the cell the same number of times of rows in column C, up until the cell is blank. Instead it copies test 1 to 4 with respect to A1 to A4.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll want to use `As Long` (32-bit signed int) to declare variables that can hold a row number; there aren't all that many reasons to use `As Integer` (16-bit signed int) in VBA with modern versions of Excel. Kudos for declaring variables as you require them! Watch out for [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference), too - these pesky buggers tend to make things not work as intended, when they don't just blow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just made simple sample here.
may be this can be more helpful.

[image: let's say this is the data. And name of the sheet is data]

On the same workbook the other sheet's name is copy. This sheet is where we transfer the data.

First thing, i will count the number of the rows on data  page.
then i will transfer the data from data page to copy page

```
Sub copy()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws_data As Worksheet
Dim ws_copy As Worksheet
Dim num_of_rows As Long

Set ws_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
Set ws_copy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("copy")



' Here I am counting number of the rows in data page
i = 1
Do While ws_data.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
i = i + 1
Loop

num_of_rows = i - 1

MsgBox (num_of_rows)


'and i will transfer the data from data page to copy page


For i = 1 To num_of_rows

ws_copy.Cells(i, 1) = ws_data.Cells(i, 1)
ws_copy.Cells(i, 2) = ws_data.Cells(i, 2)
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach can be useful with a few changes

```
do while cells(i,1) <> "" #(this is the condition to stop at empty cell)
 a=cells(i,1)
 i=i+1
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll see what I can do with it :)

Comment: I added one more line (i=i+1) changes the position of the cell

Comment: @user20109552 ()

Comment: yup thanks, but can I do this loop within another loop ?

Comment: yes loop in loop is possible

Comment: hey, I have made some what I assume good progress, if any tips you have that could direct me in the right way would be so great!